# Node.js application works in local, but not working when deployed to Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

I've a working Node js application in local i.e., if I run the following command, it works in browser while I open http://127.0.0.1:8082

```
$node server.js
```

I'm trying to build image using following:

```
docker build -t dashboard .
```

And create and run container using following:

```
docker run --name dashcont3 -p 8082:8080 -d dashboard
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

When I build and run the container and trying to open the URL in browser, it gives following error:

```
This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

What am I missing?

Comment: is your application listening by the 8080 port? according your example your local app listen in the 8082, so you should use that same port in the docker container. EXPOSE 8082 and docker run --name dashcont3 -p 8082:8082 -d dashboard

Comment: Oh it worked. I'm still not understanding how it works. In simple words, can you tell me which port should be used in the browser - left or right? And what they refer to each?

Comment: Now I tried to expose port 9000 and listen to 9000, but the application won't run if I put this command ------->>>>>  docker run --name dashcont3 -p 8080:9000 -d dashboard

Comment: The second number in `docker run -p` needs to match the port number your application is listening on; if it's configured to listen on port 8082, the second number needs to be 8082.  `EXPOSE` is mostly documentation, but should be that same number.  The browser request should point at the first number in `docker run -p`.

Comment: `docker run -p {LOCAL_PORT(your computer)} : {APPLICATION_PORT}`, this instruction links the docker network to your computer so you can access to it, also keep in mind that the port you use in the `{APPLICATION_PORT} (right side)`  should match with the port your application is using and needs to be exposed in your docker file  `EXPOSE {APPLICATION_PORT}`

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze and cperez08